# How to prove this definition of the Riemann Zeta Function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I have to prove that

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$ =  $\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1^{n+1}}{n^s} $

I know I am supposed to show my work, but I have no clue on how to proceed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}&=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)^s}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^s}\\
&=\frac1{2^s}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^s}
\end{align}
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^s}=(1-\frac{1}{2^s})\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}
$$
Now we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^s}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)^s}\\
&=(1-\frac{1}{2^s})\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}-\frac1{2^s}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}\\
&=(1-\frac1{2^{s-1}})\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Where does the first equality (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}&=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)^s}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^s}) come from?

Comment: I just used the partition of natural numbers into odd and even integers.

Comment: Great, perfectly clear!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 n)^s} = \frac{1}{2^s} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}.$$